# django: form.is_valid always giving error

Tags: django

i am working on login page but my form always gives me error, please find my code below, please see view.py it response always go to else statment of "if form.is_valid():" condition. please help

here you can see form.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

this is my view.py

```
def login_view(request):
template_name = 'user/login.html'
form_class = LoginForm

if request.method == "POST":
    form = form_class(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        try:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('user:profile')
        except:
            form = form_class(None)
            return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'custom_error': 'Error'})
    else:
        return HttpResponse("<h1>Data is invalid</h1>")

else:
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('user:profile')
    else:
        form = form_class(None)
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form,})
```

user/login.html

```
{% block body %}
<div class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="{% static 'user/images/favicon.png' %}" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            {% include 'user/form-template.html' %}
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" align="right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" autofocus>Sign In</button>
              </div>
          </div>
                </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

and finally this is my form-template.html file

```
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>{{ field.label_tag }} </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ field }}
            <div>
                <span>{{ field.errors }}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="text-danger small">{{ custom_error }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you print `form.errors` in the else statement and let us know what's the error message?

Comment: i got error message 

"username
A user with that username already exists."

I dont know why i am getting this issue... i am not trying to create new user, i am just signing in.

Comment: but here m not creating user i am just loging in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks its solved, I just Changed My Form no it looks like this.

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

now i am not using built-in form and i also changed ModelForm to Form.

Comment: but still my question is how to authenticate user by using built-in form model and view?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ModelForm`, you are going to operate on django model objects, creating, updating, etc. If you are only trying to login, use `Form` instead.